# Does Jython class automatically call setter when inheriting Java interface?

Tags: jython, pydev

I've looked through the Jython book on Jython.org and perused the Internet for some answers but I don't see anywhere that suggests the following (of what seems to me to be strange) behavior. I'm doing this using PyDev 1.5.7 in Eclipse 3.6.1 with Jython 2.5.3.

Does a Jython class that inherits from a Java interface with setters automatically call the setVal when self.val = val is executed?

Here's the Java interface:

```
package com.me.mypackage
import org.python.core.PyDictionary;

public interface MyInterface {

    public double getMaxBW();

    public boolean setMaxBW(double bw);

}
```

Here's the Jython class:

```
from com.me.mypackage import MyInterface

class MyClass(MyInterface):

  def __init__(self, maxBW):
    self.maxBW = maxBW

  def setMaxBW(self, maxBW):
    self.maxBW = maxBW

  def getMaxBW(self):
    return self.maxBW
```

When I instantiate the class, in the __init__ function:

1. setMaxBW gets called when self.maxBW = maxBW is run
2. This function call in turn runs self.maxBW = maxBW
3. This code again calls setMaxBW
4. This function call in turn runs self.maxBW = maxBW
5. Repeat forever

As a result of this infinite recursion, I get a RuntimeError after the maximum recursion depth has been reached.

One thought was that this was something nifty new-style Python classes were doing (I've spent most of my Python time with old-style classes) but this problem doesn't occur with pure Jython (in Eclipse or standalone from the command line) that doesn't inherit from the Java interface. I haven't tried the interface inheritance outside of Eclipse.

And now I reiterate my initial question but in the context of my code: Is a Jython class that inherits a Java interface with setters automatically call setMaxBW when self.maxBW =  maxBW is executed?

Comment: I don't really know the answer here, but in general Jython transforms `obj.foo` to read or write access to `foo` Java pseudoproperty *if* there is one on `obj`.  So I'd *guess* the answer to your question is "yes".  Just use `self._maxBW = maxBW` (or with double underscore for the Python version of "private").  See Python naming conventions.